# I want to judge the param datatype when insert into sqlite ,How to do? On the ios development

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, type-conversion

I want to write a generate function which for inserting the data to sqlite database in the ios development,the codes are here:

```
-(NSInteger)executeUpdateWithSql:(NSString *)sql params:(NSMutableArray *)params
{

    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= params.count; i++) {
            id param = [params objectAtIndex:i];
                sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, i, [param UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

        }
    }
    NSInteger result  =sqlite3_step(stmt);
    if (result != SQLITE_DONE){
        PBLog(@"error!");
    }
    return result;
}
```

But, if there is a int param in the params, the error message is "-[__NSCFNumber UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1dd1ea60".
I want to judge the param datatype,How to do? The datatype maybe int/float/double/bealoon/string.

Comment: how is your int/float/double/bealoon wrapped in the params?

Comment: <i>
NSString *sql =  @"INSERT INTO FavoriteStop (stopId, name, sequence, latitude, longitude, routeId, routeName, routeDestination, cityCode, createTimestamp) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, datetime('now'))";
NSMutableArray *params = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [params addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
    [params addObject:@"name"];
    [params addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.latitude]];
.......
  [_database executeUpdateWithSql:sql params:params];</i>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then you should do something like this:

```
id param = [params objectAtIndex:i];
if([param isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
{
    NSString *tmp = [param stringValue]
}
else
{
    NSString *tmp = param
}
```

the `id` can be any object type and not runt time safe.